# how to identify If all the emits reached the bolt?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a kafka spout say **KafkaSpout** which reads message say **msg** from kafka topic and emits to a bolt say **Bolt1**. **Bolt1** split this message into multiple messages **msg1**,**msg2**,..,**msgN** and emit to other bolt say **Bolt2**. Now once all the messages **msg1**,**msg2**,..,**msgN** from **Bolt1**  are emitted to **Bolt2**, I need to do some processing on the **msg**. Is there any way to identify If all the split messages reached **Bolt2** ?

Answer (score 1):

Reading through Apache Storm's [Guaranteeing Message Processing](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html) documentation page, it talks about if emitted correctly, a Tuple Tree will be generated that Storm will replay from the Spout if messages are lost.

This happens through a mechanism Storm calls anchoring, say you have the following execute method.

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    String sentence = tuple.getString(0);
    for(String word: sentence.split(" ")) {
        _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(word)); //anchoring happening
    }
    _collector.ack(tuple);
}
```

> Each word tuple is anchored by specifying the input tuple as the first
>   argument to emit. Since the word tuple is anchored, the spout tuple at
>   the root of the tree will be replayed later on if the word tuple
>   failed to be processed downstream. [link](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html)

Whereas if you emitted the new word without including the original tuple,

```
_collector.emit(new Values(word)); //no anchoring
```

> Emitting the word tuple this way causes it to be unanchored. If the
>   tuple fails be processed downstream, the root tuple will not be
>   replayed. [link](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html)